# Is Context.Provider and Context.Consumer the same as document.querySelector() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I would just like to get the text of a div in Home.js when the button is clicked... I've set up createContext();

I've tried using Refs it did not work.. so now I am trying createContext()... In themeContext.js I have a handleChange function that is being passed to Button.js when clicked I'd simply like the text content of a div in Home.js.

[live code](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-faraday-945qu?file=/src/themeContext.js)

Index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ThemeContextProvider } from "./themeContext";

import App from "./App";
const RootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeContextProvider>
    <App />
  </ThemeContextProvider>,
  RootElement
);
```

themeContext.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
const { Provider, Consumer } = React.createContext();

class ThemeContextProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    test: "test"
  };

  handleChange = () => {
    this.test.textContent
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider
        value={{ test: this.state.test, handleChange: this.handleChange }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export { ThemeContextProvider, Consumer as ThemeContextConsumer };
```

Button.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeContextConsumer } from "./themeContext";

export default function Button(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <ThemeContextConsumer>
        {context => <button onClick={context.handleChange}>ooMe</button>}
      </ThemeContextConsumer>
    </>
  );
}
```

Home.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeContextConsumer } from "./themeContext";
import Button from "./Button";

export default function Home(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <ThemeContextConsumer>
        {context => (
          <>
            <div className={context.test}>You Exposed Me!</div>
            <br />
            <h4>
              Button From Test:
              <br />
              <Button handleChange={context.handleChange} />
            </h4>
          </>
        )}
      </ThemeContextConsumer>
    </>
  );
}
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Home from "./Home";
import Another from "./Another";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Home />
      <Another />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: React Context is about passing data down to child components without having to pass them through each intermediate tree node. It doesn't even remotely compare to `querySelector()`.

Comment: Yes I’ve notice React much more difficult to use than traditional JavaScript. And hard to find decent documentation

Comment: So what is your goal here? Have one child cause a change to another child? Because "get the text of a div" sounds weird.

Comment: basically when my button is clicked  i am looking to get the text content from the div which resides in Home.js <div className={context.test}>You Exposed Me!</div>. When the button is clicked it should return You Exposed Me! similar to how document.getElementById(".test").textContent would return You Exposed Me!  I've just been trying to figure out the correct way to do this in React.js

Comment: The main problem is you need to properly use `createRef()` and `ref` first. Then you need to make them part of the context: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-darwin-x602c?file=/src/themeContext.js

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is just getting an element value then you can use refs for that.

```js
function App() {
  const divRef = React.useRef(null);

  function handleClick() {
    console.log(divRef.current.textContent);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={divRef} onClick={handleClick}>
        Foo
      </div>
      <Button onClick={handleClick} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Button({ onClick }) {
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

It is simple when you first check the basic steps for the library you are trying. There are tons of decent documentation.

Also, if you are going to use React, I highly suggest thinking in React way. You are not going to see many codes trying to get an element's value like that.

Comment: So createContext is not necessary? I can follow your example and get access to the div component with className={test} when I click the button coming from my button component?

Comment: I ask because I’ve tried using useRef in a previous attempt and received a ReferenceError test is undefined

Comment: React Context is totally another concept as @Chris G commented on your question. Again, if your intent is "only getting a div's content" as I do in my example, then you don't need anything beside refs. I don't know how you tried it but as you can see you should create a ref then set it to your element as I do in my example.

Comment: Thank you but that's not what i'm looking for as per my example. What you have is the App component which renders  a div with a ref and imports a component button. It does work but not what i'm looking for. Regardless thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have updated the link 
https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-cdn-uqc5c

Basically in react if you want to update the view you need to call

```
setState
```

to trigger a re-render

more info: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Why the downvote? there are some fundamental issues in the way op is handling state

Comment: thank you. but i am looking to get the text content from this div which resides in Home.js <div className={context.test}>You Exposed Me!</div>. When the button is clicked it should return You Exposed Me!

Comment: I downvoted because this question is about something else

Comment: You exposed me .. should be in react state 

and that classname doesnot make sense tbh

Answer (score 0):

I used @devserken example above and this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53252494/reactjs-how-to-pass-component-reference-to-another-component-as-prop) to come up with this [solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-elbakyan-vs9rv?file=/src/App.js). I used the component names from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53252494/reactjs-how-to-pass-component-reference-to-another-component-as-prop) because the component names weren't the focus of what i was trying to learn. My goal was to learn how to grab / capture DOM elements, in this particular case when the button is clicked console log the textContent.